# CodeIgniter - use MySQL 5.7 JSON_CONTAINS function

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter

So, I have a list of "whitelisted" countries (eg. `['PT', 'US', 'UK', 'ES']`) on a column of a table, and I want to check if the user's country (eg. 'US') is whitelisted, in order to show the user the row's content.

I searched and the best and easiest way I found was to compile the whitelisted list into a JSON array, make the column JSON type and use the `JSON_CONTAINS` function present on MySQL 5.7+

However, I can't figure out how to implement that with CI's database library.

How can I use CI's DB lib to use MySQL's functions? Would there be a better way to achieve this instead of JSON array?

Comment: The qery you right in mysql that same you can execute using $this->db->query('Your query') . i think this will help you.

Comment: Please, add more details, the table looks like, etc

Comment: @PankajSharma yeah, that'd do it, but I wanted to merge it with other CI where parameters.

Comment: @Gagantous what I want is really straight-forward, I have a list of stuff that is region restricted, so, for each row there's a list of country codes where that content can appear. The user has a country, with the user's country I want to return all rows that have the user's country.

Comment: from @PankajSharma said, you could use  ci library for query, 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: @Gagantous but is there a way to mix that with CI's $this->db->where and other helpers from Query Builder library?

Comment: yes you can, but i am not really understan with your question description, does your country "whitelisted" and user table, really have table in Mysql  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153889/discussion-between-darkw-and-gagantous).

Comment: @DarkW have you got solution??

Comment: @PankajSharma decided to make the column varchar and separate the country codes by commas and then make a LIKE "%$country%" query. It's not the most efficient way, but I've tested it with 100k rows and it fetches in around 1ms.

Comment: You can try yoir query with this
The qery you right in mysql that same you can execute using $this->db->query('Your query') . i think this will help you

because  if you use this( LIKE "%$country%") than your execution time will increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->db->where("(JSON_CONTAINS(field,'[\"US\"]')) > ",0);
```

The codeigniter where clause required an operator. If we provide an operator codeigniter will ignore `IS NULL`